# Using a button to trigger alarm

Tags: android, button, alarm, android-intent

So I want to use a button to lead over to a new activity that can pick between two ints(hours and mins) rather than setting an alarm. Or maybe do something different to access the value of those ints and change them? Is there a better way to code that?

My code so far is this - am I doing it right so far?

```
public class AlarmPtest extends Activity implements  android.view.View.OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button SetAlarm, SetTimer;
int hours = 1, min = 30;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Vars();

}


private void AlarmClock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    i.putExtra(android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hours);
    i.putExtra(android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, min);
    startActivity(i);

}


private void Vars() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SetAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetAlarm);
    SetTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TimerAlarm);

    SetAlarm.setOnClickListener(this);
    SetTimer.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.SetAlarm:
        Toast alarmToast = Toast.makeText(this, "you click alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        alarmToast.show();
        AlarmClock();
     case R.id.TimerAlarm:
        Toast TimerToast = Toast.makeText(this, "you get 15 min", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        TimerToast.show();
        hours = 0 ;
        min = 15;
        AlarmClock();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right, in the sense that your hours and mins will be pased in the alarm intent. And the alarm will be set if the user has Android SDK >= 9

BTW a common code convention in Java and thus Android, is to write function names starting with smallLetters. Hence, change your functions to:

```
private void alarmClock()
private void vars()
```

Otherwise, people might get the impression your referring to a Class. The same convention is used for variable names, so you will want to change your buttons as well:

```
Button setAlarm, setTimer;
```

Comment: Okay thanks! :) It won't let me add a point cause im too new but yeah. So should I pass it through a diffrent acctivity? or just use a function within my same class

Comment: No need to pass it through a different class, just use these functions within your existing class. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the [`TimePicker`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html).  This provides a nice interface to select time for an alarm.  It occurs in an `AlertDialog` type interface so you won't need to launch a new `Activity` to select the time.

Comment: I want to use an AlertDialog type of thing, but only dealing with numbers and not a time format. Much like androids stock, in other words instead of picking to set and alarm at 6am(current time 5am) you set the alarm for 1 hours and it will set the time for 6am or 6:22am when it is 5:22am.